# Android - Rename file via sideload?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, adb, side-loading

In an effort to get a WiFi adapter working I was following instructions on replacing a file called 'linker' in system/bin. Before copying the new linker file you gave I renamed my old one to linker2 because I wanted to be able to revert if needed.

After I renamed linker to linker2 my phone said I didn't have root anymore and I couldn't rename the file back.

I restarted and now am encountering an error that prevents booting. I'm in Android System Recovery with options:

```
reboot system now
apply update from ADB
wipe data/factory reset
wipe cache partition
reboot to bootloader
power down view
recovery logs
apply update from sdcard
```

If I select 'apply update via ADB' I can use ADB from my laptop, but seems the only thing I can do is sideload a file. Is it possible for me to sideload and execute a simple script to rename that file back to linker instead of linker2?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the recovery is called **<3e>**, then you'll not be able to sideload homebrew packages.

Comment: It _looks_ like a custom recovery - can you confirm by telling us its title or giving a photo of the screen? If you're indeed on custom recovery then it should work with ADB even on the main screen.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I ended up doing a full wipe. However, I was not able to see the device connected to my computer in recovery console unless I select 'apply update from ADB'. At that point, I could *only* sideload via ADB. I was not allowed to push or anything else. I did try sideloading a custom script to rename the file back but unfortunately was not able to get it working due to 'signature verification failed'. My bootloader was not unlocked and 'reboot to boatloader' would not work. I don't think I really had any other option than a full reset.